# Outlook Desktop search contacts To/Cc/Ccn fields during typing

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, office365

Our company migrate from KerioConnect to Office 365 to better manage
the emails. Lots of people in the company have the same problem, can't
search for contacts when creating a new email and typing in the "To"
field (Click on the "To" button correctly open the address book and
the contacts are shown). I have 10 contacts in my personal folder,
before the migration when I type the name of the person in the "To"
field a list with contacts appear, after the migration this doesn't
happend. Typing the name in the box appear only the email that I have
alredy write to, but not the email saved in contacts.

This seems to be a problem only for some office installation. Here is
a list of the clients:

[image]

Do you have any idea on how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export the previous contacts from KerioConnect data base into a .csv file and then import that file into your new outlook database? If user names are the same then it should link contacts to the usernames listed in the .csv. There also are various powershell scripts you can find online to migrate the contacts data.

Comment: Hi, the problem is not that I miss the contacts inside my personal folder. I can't search real-time when typing inside the "To" field, I have to click on the "To" button and search inside the address book. The real-time search only work for the contacts that I have alredy write one-time, but not for the one that I never write before. Using Outlook For Microsoft 365 MSO this real-time search inside the "To" field correctly work, but not on the others installations

Answer (score 0):

According to a number of articles, there is no way to configure Outlook to use the entire Address Book when generating auto-complete suggestions.

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10-mso_2016/outlook-2016-auto-complete-email-from-global/bea86a68-bb65-4b66-879f-c166ab70d286

> There is no setting that I'm aware of that would enable Outlook (desktop) to search the GAL which is part of the Outlook Address Book which in turn is what gets opened when you click on TO/Cc/Bcc.

- https://www.msoutlook.info/question/53

> [T]he AutoSuggest feature doesn’t have a direct relation to your Contacts folder or other address lists configured in your Address Book. Instead, AutoSuggest uses a cache which contains a list of addresses that you’ve previously used.

If you have a small(ish) number of contacts in the address book, there is a workaround that will load them into the AutoSuggest cache. From https://www.msoutlook.info/question/filling-the-autocomplete-list-with-contact-addresses :

> You can directly fill the Auto-Complete list again by creating a new message addressed to all your contacts at once. There is no need to actually send this message.
>
> 1. Create a new message.
> 2. Press the To… button.
> 3. Select the contact list in the right top corner from which you would like to add the contacts from. Examples; Contacts folder, Global Address List (GAL) or a contacts folder in a Public folder.
> 4. Select the first contact.
> 5. Scroll all the way down to your last contact.
> 6. Hold the SHIFT button on your keyboard while clicking on the last contact to select them all.
> 7. Press the To –> button to add them all to the To… field.
> 8. Repeat step 3 to 7 if you have contacts in additional lists that you would like to add.
> 9. Press OK to close the dialog and to return to the newly created message.
> 10. Now, depending on your Outlook version, do the following;
>
> - Outlook 2007: Close the message and press “No” when prompted to save changes.
> - Outlook 2010 / 2013 / 2016 / 2019 / Office 365: You must send the message to actually store these addresses in the AutoSuggest cache. However, by placing Outlook in Offline Mode first via the Send/Receive tab, you can easily prevent it from actually being sent by removing it from the Outbox and then place Outlook back online mode.
>
> Now when you address a new message, the AutoSuggest/Auto-Complete feature will pop-up again.

Answer (score 0):

> Typing the name in the box appear only the email that I have alredy write to, but not the email saved in contacts.

By this, do you mean the autocomplete list only shows "Recent People" but no "Other Suggestions" or "Suggestions"?
If possible, could you remove all personal information and share a screenshot of both the working and non-working scenario so that we can understand better about the situation?

> before the migration when I type the name of the person in the "To" field a list with contacts appear, after the migration this doesn't happend.

Was the office version changed after the migration?

Besides, please try testing on one of the problematic machine by creating a new Outlook profile and see if there would be any difference.